# UIViewController with Nib File and Inheritance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, inheritance, uiviewcontroller, nib

I'm trying to do something really tricky and I'm still stuck at a point. I'm attempting to instance an `UIViewController` with a Nib file inherited from an other `UIViewController` with an other Nib file.
The problem is when I instantiate my son `UIViewController` .

```
// SonViewController
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil 
                bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil 
                                bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
```

The init method `initWithNibName:bundle:` should call the `super class` but it only call its own nib file. In the super class, I tried to override the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method and put the nibName myself like that :

```
// MotherViewController
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil 
               bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:@"MotherViewController" 
                                bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
```

It only init and display the `Mother Class` and its IB Object. I understand why but I begin thinking it is impossible to do what I want. Any suggestion ?

Edit:
I would use my SonViewController just like that :

```
SonViewController *son = [[SonViewController alloc] 
                      initWithNibName:@"SonViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:son animated:YES];
[son release];
```

It should display son and mother IB Object...

Regards,
kl94

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old thread, but I just found an incredibly blog post [here](http://jeffmenter.wordpress.com/2013/08/17/using-uiviewcontroller-class-inheritance-with-nib-files/).

Essentially, you have to iterate through all the views of the parent class and add them as subviews to your child class. Here's how I implemented it in my project:

```
// ChildViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self addSubviewsFromSuperclass];  
}

// ParentViewController.h
- (void)addSubviewsFromSuperclass;   

// ParentViewController.m
- (void)addSubviewsFromSuperclass
{
    UIView *selfView = self.view;
    UIView *nibView = nil;
    @try
    {
        nibView = [NSBundle.mainBundle loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self superclass]) owner:self options:nil][0];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"Something exceptional happened while loading nib:\n%@", exception);
    }
    self.view = selfView;
    for (UIView *view in nibView.subviews)
    {
        [self.view addSubview:view];
    }
}
```

That **addSuviewsFromSuperclass** method is not my coding. I have to give full credit to the author of the blogpost I mentioned above. Download his example project and you'll find it in his JMViewController.m.

Comment: As you said, this is a very old post. BUT now, because of you, I/We do know how to create 2 view controllers with 2 xib and making one them inherit from the other. Thank u

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you should only use a specific nib in the init method, and not the initWithNibName:bundle:, for this reason.

```
@implementation MotherViewController
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        //custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
- (id)init {
    return [self initWithNibName:@"MotherViewController" bundle:nil];
}
```

Then, to use the default nib for MotherViewController, you just use `[[MotherViewController alloc] init];`.

As an alternate, you could define a different initializer in MotherViewController for this reason.

```
@implementation MotherViewController
- (id)_initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        //custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    return [self _initWithNibName:@"MotherViewController" bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
}
```

Then, use a private category interface to tell SonViewController about this method.

```
//SonViewController.m
@interface MotherViewController (PrivateInit)
- (id)_initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;
@end
@implementation SonViewController
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        //custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I did't manage it to work. I've update my post to show I wanna use my SonViewController