# Is inheritance supported for view controllers and nibs

Tags: iphone

I am creating 2 view controllers and 2 nibs for each of the supported orientations of my app - portrait and landscape as recommended by [apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW26).

The problem is that I am going to have loads of duplicated code - will inheritance work in interface builder?

i.e. can I declare a iboutlet label in a base class and use it for both of the nibs?

EDIT:  I have 2 controllers, both inherit from a basecontroller.  Can I have my IBactions and IBOutlets and arrays and tableview delegate code in the base and then link it from 2 different nibs?  I am trying to get rid of some duplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: can I declare a iboutlet label in a base class and use it for both of the nibs?

A: Yes it will work, use initWithNibName to initialize the controller with the desired Nib(xib).

Comment: can you update your answer after my last edit (if there any changes).  I just want to be sure before I go down this route - if it works it will save me a lot of time!

Comment: @thelearner yes, it's possible. You can try with a simple 1 IBOutlet, it should take 3 minutes :)

Comment: @inovation - just to let you know that this is not working because when the child class calls super dealloc it releases all the outlets and controls which the other child might need.  see this question: http://tinyurl.com/3m5nh75

Comment: @thelearner I don't understand, don't you have two instances: vController1 and vController2 ? calling in vController1 [super doSomething] can't affect vController2.

Answer (score 0):

I just posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753742/uiviewcontroller-with-nib-file-and-inheritance) but I thought you could benefit from this as well.

I know this is an old thread, but I just found an incredibly blog post [here](http://jeffmenter.wordpress.com/2013/08/17/using-uiviewcontroller-class-inheritance-with-nib-files/).

Essentially, you have to iterate through all the views of the parent class and add them as subviews to your child class. Here's how I implemented it in my project:

```
// ChildViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self addSubviewsFromSuperclass];  
}

// ParentViewController.h
- (void)addSubviewsFromSuperclass;   

// ParentViewController.m
- (void)addSubviewsFromSuperclass
{
    UIView *selfView = self.view;
    UIView *nibView = nil;
    @try
    {
        nibView = [NSBundle.mainBundle loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self superclass]) owner:self options:nil][0];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"Something exceptional happened while loading nib:\n%@", exception);
    }
    self.view = selfView;
    for (UIView *view in nibView.subviews)
    {
        [self.view addSubview:view];
    }
}
```

That **addSuviewsFromSuperclass** method is not my coding. I have to give full credit to the author of the blogpost I mentioned above. Download his example project and you'll find it in his JMViewController.m.